# EWS Managed Api - Retrieving e-mails from Office365 exchange server

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices, email-attachments

I was initially connecting to an on-domain exchange server and retrieving attachment files from e-mails in my inbox. This worked great, it was authenticating, retrieving the files (even other folders). Now I've switched to an Office365 exchange server.

I have read the documentation and understand that the following needs to be false and you have to pass through the credentials manually as you can see below.

```
// Service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
Service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(ExchangeEmail, ExchangePassword);
```

So I've done these changes, I've got my ExchangeService's ExchangeVersion on "Exchange2013_SP1.

From inspecting the Service after the .AutodiscoverUrl call, it can be seen that it's retrieving a url etc. So it looks like it is definitely connecting to the server. I'm out of ideas now, I've followed the msdn page for EWS Managed Api and can't quite figure out why it's now no longer picking out the e-mails.

Another important point is I'm doing a filter search (which worked in the domain exchange). The structure of the Domain e-mail is the same as the office365 e-mail.

This is the snippet where I'm unable to find items from :

```
var view = new ItemView(10, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning)
                       {
                           PropertySet =
                               new PropertySet(
                               BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
                               EmailMessageSchema.Sender,
                               ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived)
                       };

        var filter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.From, FromEmailAddress);
        FindItemsResults<Item> results;

        do
        {
            results = Service.FindItems(vacancyFolderId, filter, view);
```

Another test I've done is to keep it simple and just try send an e-mail through the ews managed api. That works as expected. I'm suspecting there is a subtle change that needs making to my attachment retrieving code. Perhaps it's https or something but there is no mention of that in the documentation. There is only mention that you need to have https enabled for accessing exchange servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were 2 problems with the way I was trying to filter by the "from email address".

**1st problem** was what Jason mentions. In my ItemView I had included the PropertySet value 'EmailMessageSchema.Sender' and this isn't a string. Changing that to 'EmailMessageSchema.From" made no difference when trying to filter on the Office365 exchange server.

Note: Using this incorrect property set (.Sender) on a Domain exchange server still works for whatever weird reason.

**2nd Problem** When querying the Office365 server with the following syntax to filter by :

```
var filter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.From, FromEmailAddress);
```

Does not work. When inspecting the incoming From it's not an e-mail address it is a "Username/Domain/Otherthings/Admin Group/Etc/Etc" .

**Solution** Use the querystring filter.

```
var querystring = "HasAttachments:true From:foo@bar.com Kind:email";
```

I hope this helps someone and saves them the frustration this has caused me. From the documentation I've seen (SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring and the EWS Managed Api getting starting..) there isn't any mention of this.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you, I think you're saying that `FindItems` returns no results. Doing a `ContainsSubstring` filter on the `Sender` property is problematic (since Sender isn't a string property). See [EWS SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring to filter on Sender Email Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458685/ews-searchfilter-containssubstring-to-filter-on-sender-email-address).

Comment: Just this moment I noticed this. First problem was my Property set didn't even have a Sender property included in it's instantiation and second thing is your mentioned string issue. I've now tried to change the EmailMessageSchema.From and tried to filter on that but no issue. But I'm glad I've spotted it.

Comment: For some reason the From that is returned by EmailMessageSchema.From is different in a domain exchange server to Office365.